# Go & Docker: I'm able to run a go web server when using stdlib, when I use custom packages errors occur

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Note the code works perfectly fine when I'm running the code on my laptop.

The following two groups of code will run on my laptop. However the second group (which uses my custom package) doesn't work on Elastic Beanstalk running docker.

**Standard Lib only**

```
import (
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = "3000"
    }
    http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, nil)
}
```

**Uses Custom Package**

```
import (
    "os"

    "github.com/sim/handlers"
)

func main() {
    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = "3000"
    }
    handlers.ServeAndHandle(port) // wrapper of ListenAndServe
}
```

**Error Messages**:

```
Failed to build Docker image aws_beanstalk/staging-app: andlers: exit status 128 [0mtime="2015-08-14T05:08:17Z" level="info" msg="The command [/bin/sh -c go-wrapper download] returned a non-zero code: 1" . Check snapshot logs for details.

2015-08-14 01:08:15 UTC-0400    WARN    Failed to build Docker image aws_beanstalk/staging-app, retrying...
```

**cron.yaml**

```
version: 1
cron: 
  - name: "task1"
    url: "/scheduled"
    schedule: "* * * * *"
```

Comment: Did you try it on you machine with docker? May simply be some dependency of the package, that is present on your machine, but missing in the docker image you used in elastic beanstalk.

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile too?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I don't have a dockerfile. I think Elastic beanstalk takes care it for you. Maybe I should create one.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `Dockerfile` or/and `Dockerrun.aws.json` for your environment as per the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html)

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM FROM golang:1.3-onbuild

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["go run <your.go.file>"]
```

**Dockerrun.aws.json**

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "golang:1.3-onbuild",   # <-- don't need this if you are using a Dockerfile
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "3000"
    }
  ],
  "Logging": "/var/log/go"
}
```

Using the `eb` command line to deploy ?